# Deezer API search tracks - empty result with Remix keyword

Tags: api, deezer

Why [this request](https://api.deezer.com/search?limit=50&q=Birdy%20Nam%20Nam%20-%20Abesses%20(Beat%20Torrent%20Remix)) does not return any result?

```
https://api.deezer.com/search?limit=50&q=Birdy%20Nam%20Nam%20-%20Abesses%20(Beat%20Torrent%20Remix)
```

And [this one](https://api.deezer.com/search?limit=50&q=Abesses%20(Beat%20Torrent%20Remix)) too (without artist).

But when I [remove the "Remix"](https://api.deezer.com/search?limit=50&q=Birdy%20Nam%20Nam%20-%20Abesses%20(Beat%20Torrent%20)), I got the result I am looking for :

```
{"data":[{"id":7510375,"readable":true,"title":"Abesses (Beat Torrent Remix)","link":"http:\/\/www.deezer.com\/track\/7510375","duration":193,"rank":632207,"explicit_lyrics":false,"preview":"http:\/\/cdn-preview-7.deezer.com\/stream\/79cb4d79f8ce55dd95c0b51b6f66699a-2.mp3","artist":{"id":1215,"name":"Birdy Nam Nam","link":"http:\/\/www.deezer.com\/artist\/1215","picture":"https:\/\/api.deezer.com\/artist\/1215\/image","tracklist":"https:\/\/api.deezer.com\/artist\/1215\/top?limit=50","type":"artist"},"album":{"id":692538,"title":"Beat Torrent Reworks","cover":"https:\/\/api.deezer.com\/album\/692538\/image","tracklist":"https:\/\/api.deezer.com\/album\/692538\/tracks","type":"album"},"type":"track"}],"total":1}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It can happen on some tracks because some track titles are composed of the real title (i.e. "Abesses") and the track version (i.e "(Beat Torrent Remix)"), so the search can be truncated sometimes.

Comment: OK, thanks, but then why the [Birdy Nam Nam - Abesses (Beat Torrent)](https://api.deezer.com/search?limit=50&q=Birdy%20Nam%20Nam%20-%20Abesses%20(Beat%20Torrent)) request works? Do you advise to remove all alternate version informations from the request?

Comment: It can help to minimize the search value, the track version is cut in different fields.